# jquery-ui buttons sometimes slow to render, css alternative?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery-ui. The button support looks good, the stylized buttons are nice. The only downside is that it looks like the rendering of the button is done in javascript, so sometimes there is a pause when the page loads and you see all the buttons change form from native buttons to the jquery-ui style buttons.

Are there any 'button makers' out there that can just generate css for a button that I can just apply to a div to get the same effect? Was thinking maybe if I do the button styling myself, the browser will prepare it before the page is ever shown to the user, avoiding that awkward pause.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

A couple of things - first of all, if you're only doing this to create static buttons (read: not as replacements for checkboxes or radiobuttons), you can always use the HTML generated by the JavaScript without actually having to call the `.button` function on them. When inspecting the element after the `button` function has been called on it, you'll notice the HTML has been changed slightly, and several classes has been added to the element:

```
<a class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" href="#" role="button">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Button Content</span>
</a>
```

Unfortunately, the jQuery UI CSS generated does not include the `:hover` and `:active` pseudo-classes, but we can easily fix that. Search in CSS for the `ui-state-hover` and `ui-state-active`, and add in the appropriate pseudo-classes manually.

---

Alternatively, you can also roll your own, like for instance what I have done in the example presented below. It replicates the font and background color of the original buttons in a class that is removed upon the application of the jQuery UI styles:

> http://www.jsfiddle.net/ZkWP8/

In the example, we use an themeroller jQuery UI theme *without* the CSS modifications mentioned above. Execution of the `.button` delayed by several seconds to emulate network delays in loading the script and images.

Comment: I've made a new version of this for jQuery UI 1.10.4 and I've also added :hover and :active support. And for anyone who wants it you can also emulate the jQuery UI appearance without any javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/spinal007/FntBG/

Answer (score 3):

This is called a Flash Of Unstyled Content (FOUC). There is a way around it by adding `display:none;` to the element that the buttons are appearing in and then using `.show()` on the `$(document).ready()`. This will ensure your buttons always appear styled.

There is one drawback and that is your site will not degrade gracefully should a user disable javascript.

Comment: Another drawback with this strategy is that some JavaScript libraries will not render correctly if they are not visible when initialized. For example, the SlickGrid library won't be able to get the container dimensions and will render incorrectly or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI adds a class of "ui-button" to the element (or the element's label in the case of checkboxes and radio buttons). So you can use this to hide the element with CSS before jQuery UI acts upon it and show it once the script has run.

Example, if your button have a class of "button":

```
.button {
    display: none;
}

.button.ui-button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved by finding optimal place for executing jquery button style stuff - not in ready handler. Optimal place I mean the place in html code after the buttons and before the stuff which generates delays and of course not in ready (so indeed before ready event, relates to time point, not html place).

Below is code which we normally put as ready handler, but now we put it in optimal place

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input[type=submit], a, input[type=button], button").button();
    });
</script>
```

Besides for sureness that everything will be styled properly (other buttons placed later and about which we forgot) we can executing it in ready too.

Answer (score 0):

I use a div to cover the entire body until all the styles are applied.  After things are jquery-ui-ified, I hide the div.  [See here.](http://jsfiddle.net/AhYgg/200/)

The div to cover the body uses these styles:

```
.load-mask 
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 10000;
    background-color: #DFE8F6;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers to this were quite outdated so I thought I'd share my updated solution to this.

- It's been specifically designed for jQuery 1.10.4 (the default layout may change in future versions)
- It supports :hover and :active effects so that the same effects can be achieved without any javascript

Opaque background:
http://jsfiddle.net/spinal007/FntBG/

```
.button{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;

    line-height:1.4;
    margin: 0 0.1em 0 0;
    padding: 0.3em 1em 0.4em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 1px #FFF inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 1px #FFF inset;

    color: #666;
    background: #EFEFEF;

    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Segoe UI, Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:1.1em;
}
.button:hover{
    background-color:#f9f9f9;   
    border-color:#999999;
    color: #212121;
}
.button:active{
    background-color:#71B800;   
    border-color:#64A300;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

And here's an alternative with CSS3 Gradient background:
http://jsfiddle.net/spinal007/pVVs3/
(you may want this, depending on your theme!)